# Gantry 5.1.2 - Layout Block Width

Tags: css, joomla

This is a really simple question..but in Gantry 5.1.2, I'm attempting to set three block elements in the template - layout for the header in a horizontal row. From left to right:

1. a menu for registered members       (70%)   (acl registered)
2. login block for guests              (10%)   (acl public)
3. login block for signed in users     (20%)   (acl registered)

I have this configured, problem is item 1 - the menu is only visible to registered clients, it collapses causing item 2 to move to the far left as item 1 no longer takes up 70%. How can I make item 2 login block remain aligned to the right portion of the page (positioned as if the 70% menu hadn't collapsed) without using css positioning?

I've tried using spacers, but they remain once logged in. I then tried adding a transparent border and setting a width, but that will cause other issues I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a more proper way to do this, but my solution for now is to create a new menu item with a single alpha character and set it to public as a menu heading type within the client menu. Add a css class to this menu item with display: none to remove the character from the menu directory.

Seems like a silly fix for something I'm sure Gantry can handle.

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the particle gear in Layout Manager and under the Block tab you can select the "Fixed Size". This will make the Login block to be fixed at 20% no matter the surrounding.